# Error with array displaying

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int move_player() {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) && current_x<max_x) {
        int old_x = current_x;
        int new_x = current_x+1;
        path[old_x] = '_';
        path[new_x] = player;
        system("cls");
        cout << endl;
        for (int a=0; a <= 9; a++) {
            cout << path[a];
        }
    } else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)  && current_x>min_x) {
        int old_x = current_x;
        int new_x = current_x-1;
        path[old_x] = '_';
        path[new_x]=player;
        system("cls");
        cout << endl;
        for (int b = 0; b <= 9; b++) {
            cout << path[b];
        }
    }
    return current_x;
}
```

What the bulk of code does is it just moves around an object (only right or left). It starts by showing the object on the far left and then I can move it right once but after it just does nothing when I press the right or left key.
How can I solve it?

Comment: You never seem to modify `current_x` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve it?

You'll need to use a `while` loop around the `if-else` block.

or

call `move_player` in a `while` loop in the calling function.

Comment: inside main: `while (true) { current_x = movePlayer(); }`? No?

Comment: @TimStraubinger, for that work, the value returned from `move_player` has to be `new_x`. That might be the source of the problem.

Comment: @RSahu true, I didn't catch that while trying to provide OP with something working. `current_x` should be modified meaningfully within `move_player()`

Comment: By returning new_x from move_player and setting current_x to move_player in the while loop kind of works but the char just moves way too fast. I wanted to initially move the char by 1 through the array